# How to pipe a remote shell script to windows equivalent of bash

Tags: windows, bash, shell, curl

So I just learned (similar to [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)) that you can evaluate remote scripts using this:

```
bash <(curl https://foo.bar)
```

Something like that. Now I would like to do this same thing for windows *without installing anything that doesn't come preinstalled on windows*.

```
bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal http://downloadsrv/10mb.zip c:\10mb.zip
```

That seems to be the [go to approach](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-or-curl) for downloading files on Windows. So I'm wondering how to take something like that and evaluate it as it's being downloaded like that. If not possible, then any standard workaround would be helpful.

Comment: `bash <(curl https://foo.bar)` [DON'T DO THIS!](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12766049)

Comment: The article https://gnu.moe/wallofshame.md can't be reached.

Comment: What is the security problem? I don't get it.

Comment: TL;DR: Running a remote script directly in the shell is highly discouraged, because (1) it is unsafe. The script can be changed from the last time you read it. (2) even if the script is trusted, your network connection can break and your download can be incomplete; causing you to run the partial script. (e.g. good old `rm -rf /` instead of `rm -rf /tmp/mydata`)

Comment: You can google about "curl pipe bash pitfalls" for may other examples.